# How to setup video/graphics correctly on the Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: video, archlinux, xorg

My question is similar to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64079/how-can-i-setup-the-video-graphics-on-the-raspberry-pi-3). However I need to clarify some details.

1. I can't find anything about this statement *"I also read that the vc4 driver does not use the gpu_mem parameter, confusing things a bit."* in the original question.

   Moreover, in Gentoo wiki https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_VC4 I see this: *"It's also recommended to bump your gpu_mem to 128 (it's what raspi-config does when you enable the driver through it)."*, that means. that gpu_mem is used on every type of graphic mode.
2. So we have xf86-video-fbturbo-git and KMS driver. First one is good for 2D acceleration, second one for 3d. But, as I know, KMS driver implements in xorg.conf via modesetting driver, which does not support 2D acceleration (https://linux.die.net/man/4/modesetting), so only 3D will work good but no 2D scrolling. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know certainly, for those cases i just install a common OS, like raspbian that have much more support than others. i have been never had any graphics issue before with raspbian, if you want to add other kind of display devices you have to get correct codecs ( or drivers for each ).